# Does the Dragon Ball Heroes opening 5 have any meaning for Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Heroes opening 5,

(be careful, possible spoiler or not)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49_g2XnJGAA

> We see Goku, Freezer, and Jiren are the only players left in the tournament of power. [image]

Does this have any relevance for what's going to happen in Dragon Ball Super?

Comment: Dragon Ball Heroes, you mean it as that game that is avalible for arcade or somethinge else? Also i kind of doubt it has anything to do with how the tournamnet will end but you can never be sure

Comment: it's a videogame with some story, but it also expanded its story through official Dragon Ball Heroes mangas, some of them written by Toyotaro (same artist of Dragon Ball Super manga) and published by Shueisha (same publisher of Dragon Ball Super manga and owner of Dragon Ball mangas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Dragon Ball Hero has nothing to do with Dragon Ball Super. There are many fighters such as Omega Shenron, SSJ4 Gogeta, Broly etc in dragon ball heroes who aren't considered to be canon. Even if Freiza, Goku and Jiren happen to be the last 3 standing in dragon ball super, it would only be a coincidence.

Comment: I'm not so sure now because the last 2 characters from Goku's universe are Goku and Freezer just like in Dragon Ball Heroes

Comment: +Pablo It has nothing to do with Dragon Ball Heroes. For instance, it was initially believed that the fighters would be eliminated in the same order as the dragon ball star from the opening which held true to a certain extent. It was also predicted that Goku and Gohan would be the last 2 standing based on the old ending. It's just a coincidence.

Comment: I think they spoiled the end in Dragon Ball Heroes in purpose.

Comment: +Pablo Not really. That is just an assumption and coincidence. Even without Dragon Ball Heroes, it was obvious that Freiza was going to last until the end as they hadn't done anything significant with him throughout the tournament while all the other fighters had their time to shine. Nobody expected Android 17 to outlast or yet alone die but it happened.